# How to make a "soft-textured emission" (example provided)

Tags: rendering, materials, shaders, compositing-nodes, emission

I'm trying to copy this

[image: Zoomed in]

So far I've got this

[image]

My material nodes look like this Material Nodes (yellow cube material is the same, just new colour)

[image]

My Composite nodes look like this Compositing Nodes (it's just a glare node for the 'glow')

[image]

My focus is on the cubes, not the foggy coloured background.

**Here's what i think i'm missing:**

- Common texture between all cube materials for "bump" on the cubes
- Blueish Point Light from Above
- Less harsh emissions from my materials

**Here's what i'd like some help understanding:**

The yellow cube has two base colours that blend together, the yellow & orange. You can see the same blend in the red & pink above it and below it. I'm thinking it might be a subsurface scatter but i can't tell.

**How can I copy the look of the cubes?**

---

Source: https://www.ordinaryfolk.co/

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get pretty good results with *Translucent BSDF* and a point light inside.

- Emission shader isn't best, because it's uniform across the whole surface, nad doesn't receive shadows.
- Settings are the same for both engines, but *Cycles* uses slightly lighter translucency color
- For Eevee I enabled *Bloom*, for Cycles I'd probably use *Glare node* in Compositor.

[image]

[image]